# Preview + tikz extraction no longer working (TL 2014)

Tags: tikz-pgf, preview

I'm trying to regenerate an old document where I used to extract `tikz` figures using `preview` and I'm getting into a problem where `preview` extracts *every* page of the document rather than just the `tikzpicture` environments. The setup for preview are in this [`prelude.sty`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlunix/blob/master/src/prelude.sty#L263-264), included [here](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlunix/blob/master/src/ocamlunix.tex#L32).

Here's the way I invoke the extraction:

```
pdflatex -file-line-error -halt-on-error '-interaction=nonstopmode' \
  '-output-directory=src' '-jobname=ocamlunix-image' \
  '\PassOptionsToPackage{active}{preview}\input{src/ocamlunix.tex}'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.
(./src/ocamlunix.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2013/05/30 v3.7b configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
 [...]
Output written on src/ocamlunix-image.pdf (160 pages, 849607 bytes).
```

Any hints about what may be going on ?

Comment: Perhaps this here: http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/316/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I'm not sure if we can be really helpful. Your log shows 130-page document. Do you think it would be possible to bring it down to lets say a 4-page document, whose whole source could then go into the question? See also [Minimal Working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for more information.

Comment: Ulrike, is there an easy way to apply your patch to a working document if I try to add it to my prelude I get a stackoverflow ? tohecz, I look into that if Ulrike's fix doesn't work.

Comment: So I tried to directly hack `texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def` and that is indeed the problem. As you indicated this also solves http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/315/ which I also had in my build system. Could you maybe make an answer that I can accept ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: As Daniel asked --  is there an easy way to apply your patch to a working document? I've opened a question for this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235733/8057